# SetTimeout or use database to track next function trigger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, settimeout

I have an app where I'm updating data from various APIs and storing it locally.  The data in each API is updated at different intervals...3 seconds, 15 seconds, and 30+ seconds.

At the moment, I'm updating each API and then setting a `setTimeout` to schedule the next update.  It works...but is this optimal?

Another option I've considered is to include a field named `nextUpdate` in my database model that takes a Number (Unix timestamp), and then query the database once per second for any objects that are scheduled to update with mongoose, such as `.find({ nextUpdate: { $gt: Date.now() / 1000 })`.  My concern was that this would cause too many unnecessary calls (and frankly this is my first app so I don't know how many mongo requests per second is considered too much).  I'm currently using Mlab as my database host.

So would you continue using setTimeout?  The database refresh option I've proposed above?  Or another solution?

Thanks in advance for your time and advice.

Comment: My own opinion is that if the end user does not have to be able to change the interval at will or if the data does not have to be stored longterm, using a database for it is overkill. Keep it as a constant in the code. Or a config file. Unless you have to be able to say that link A refreshed every 17 seconds, 5 years from now.

Comment: Thanks - definitely is a constant refresh interval per API.  Glad to hear I probably did it right the first time!

Answer (score 0):

I would keep using the first approach, though `setInterval` would be more fitting here.

The second approach seems like it only has downsides to it, unless I'm missing something?

(I would have liked to post this as a comment but cannot post comments yet)

Comment: Thanks!  I'll take a look at setInterval.